# aggregate and concatenate the remaining unique elements in the output

Tags: r, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I want to aggregate based on two columns and get the output with all the unique elements in each column. For example, in the dataset below, the blank space are NAs and I want to sum the trips based on o and d (which I did). But the element A in both o and d column does not have its other pair and hence not appearing in output. How can I include A once in both column and make trips 0 (corresponding to all As). The output matrix I want is also attached.
Thanks in advance!

**CODE**

```
df<-read.csv("smallexample.csv",header = TRUE)
df[["trips"]][is.na(df[["trips"]])] <- 0
#aggregating the trips 
result1<-aggregate(trips ~o+d, data=df,sum)
#change from long to wide format
result2<-dcast(result1, o ~ d)
```

***DATA***

```
structure(list(o = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), d = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"A", "B", "C", "E"), class = "factor"), trips = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 
1.5, NA, NA, 1, 4, NA, 6, NA, 0.5, 6, 2, 1)), .Names = c("o", 
"d", "trips"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

**OUPUT:**

```
structure(list(X = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), class = "factor"), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 
0L, 10L, 0L, 3L), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
lev <- LETTERS[1:5]
# Change the columns into factor to prevent dropping
df %>%
  mutate(o=factor(o, lev), d=factor(d, lev)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(o), !is.na(d)) %>%
  dcast(o ~ d, sum, drop=FALSE)

  o A  B C D E
1 A 0  0 0 0 0
2 B 0  0 1 0 0
3 C 0 10 0 0 6
4 D 0  0 0 0 0
5 E 0  3 0 0 0
```

Comment: Works perfect for this small example! I am trying to implement it into a big problem where it is US states instead of letters and trying to save them in a separate file is not working.

Comment: Can you provide some examples to illustrate?

Comment: Got it! I should use-factor(dataset$variable, levels = sort(unique(dataset$variable)), ordered=TRUE) instead. Anyway, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, (1:2) := lapply(.SD, factor, levels = LETTERS[1:5]),
       .SDcols = o:d][!is.na(o) & !is.na(d)], o ~d, sum, drop = FALSE)
#   o A  B C D E
#1: A 0  0 0 0 0
#2: B 0  0 1 0 0
#3: C 0 10 0 0 6
#4: D 0  0 0 0 0
#5: E 0  3 0 0 0
```

Comment: Had to make a slight adjustment but thanks a lot for the simpler version!